# OSMnx: How to get OSMnx stats from a GeoSeries

Tags: osmnx

I would like to get the OSMnx stats for a GeoSeries in Python. I have a GeoSeries with 406 Polygons and I would like to have the OSMnx for each Polygon.

I succeed to get the OSMnx stats for a single Polygon. Herefore I used the following code:

```
polygonsnew = polygons.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})
osm = ox.core.graph_from_polygon(polygonsnew[101], network_type='drive')
stats = ox.basic_stats(osm)
stats
```

When I tried to get the graph for all the polygons by:

```
osm = ox.core.graph_from_polygon(polygonsnew, network_type='drive')
```

I get this error-message:

```
   1730     # verify that the geometry is valid and is a shapely Polygon/MultiPolygon
   1731     # before proceeding
```

I would like to know if there is a way to get the stats for all polygons. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [in the docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.core.graph_from_polygon), `graph_from_polygon` takes a shapely Polygon or MultiPolygon, but you are passing it a GeoSeries. To get the graphs for all the polygons in a GeoSeries, you can either:

1. Do them all at once in one single graph by taking the `unary_union` of the GeoSeries then passing its resulting (Multi)Polygon to OSMnx.
2. Do them one at a time, by looping through your GeoSeries and passing the geometries one at a time to OSMnx.